# Нужна ли запятая после слова "поздравляю"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Поздравляю Виктора с первой победой

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна:

**Поздравляю** (кого?) **Виктора...**

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна:

**Поздравляю Виктора с первой победой.**

Здесь нет обращения к лицу.

Сравнить: *Виктор, поздравляю тебя с первой победой.*

**Обращение** — это сло­во или сло­во­со­че­та­ние, обо­зна­ча­ю­щее лицо или пред­мет, к кото­ро­му обра­ще­на речь, при этом используется **форма И.п.**

В данном случае сообщение адресовано тому, кто знает Виктора.